# Corona image change scene when touch

Tags: android, image, lua, popup, coronasdk

I have a lot of images, I'm trying to do when click on image show details (I was looking for popup tutorial when touch image shows popup with details and a bit of history of the image) I didn't find anything so I had the idea (open new scene) but I don't know how do it.

I have this:

```
local archers = display.newImageRect( "cards/archers.png", 50, 50 )
archers.x = 30
archers.y = -18
```

i tried this:

```
local function Archercall( event )
composer.gotoScene( "Archer" )
end

local archers = display.newImageRect( "cards/archers.png", 50, 50, onPress=Archercall )
archers.x = 30
archers.y = -18
```

But it gives me an error, if possible need pop-up integration when click image or just how open scene when click image.

I think will be more clean and better with pop-up method.

Thanks.

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/e96uwy.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

to open scene, try:

```
local function onObjectTouch( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        composer.gotoScene( "Archer" )
    end
    return true
end
archers:addEventListener( "touch", onObjectTouch )
```

read more:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html

popup menu:
in this thread 
https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/62108-implementing-ui-based-on-ios-7-google-material/
link to git with many examples (look menu.lua-> Open Dialog)